# Property of update selection can't be found

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm trying to follow Mike's example on [Object Constancy](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/). I have a bar chart and my data is an array of objects like this:

```
var data = [{id: "A", amount: 1.1}, {id: "B", amount: 9.8}, {...}, ...]
```

The specified key function uses "id"

```
var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data, d => d.id);
```

bar.enter works as expected, I get a bar of the preselected value (from the option of the menu), but updating

```
var barUpdate = d3.transition(bar)
  .attr("transform", d => "translate(" + (d.x0 = xScale(d.id)) + ")");
```

is complaining about

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

I'm a little confused, why d.id is not defined, I expected the key function to make the correct object with its properties available (.id and .amount). Any help with that would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: don't put a selection as transition argument `bar.transition().attr(...)`

Comment: thanks for the hint, the arguments for .transistion() changed from v3 to the what I use (v5) and now it works